# Programmatic Form POST from jQuery doesnt work in document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the below script in my code:

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready()
        {
            $("#hdnTest").text('@ViewBag.Test');                
            $("#frmRouter").submit();
        };

        function submitform()
        {
            $("#frmRouter").submit();
        }
    </script>
```

I also have the below html in my mvc view:

```
<form id="frmRouter" method="post" action="https://localhost/Destination/Index">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" id="hdnTest" name="hdnTestName"  />
        </div>
        <a href="#null" onclick="submitform();">Click</a>
    </form>
```

When I click on the hyper link, the form is getting posted to the action URL. However, the form submit inside the document.ready doesn't work. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document.ready has not the correct syntax.
You have two ways to perform a document.ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#hdnTest").text('@ViewBag.Test');
    $("#frmRouter").submit();
});

$(function () {
    $("#hdnTest").text('@ViewBag.Test');
    $("#frmRouter").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You've written the code in a way that's syntactically correct, but functionally wrong:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#hdnTest").text('@ViewBag.Test');                
        $("#frmRouter").submit();
    });
```

is what you want. The `.ready()` method should be passed a reference to a function. It doesn't have to be an anonymous function (as above), but that's pretty common.

Your code was missing the function, so jQuery just basically ignored the method call. The subsequent block of code was executed, but since the form element didn't exist in the DOM it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#id_of_your_anchor_tag").click(function(){
         $("#hdnTest").text('@ViewBag.Test');                
        $("#frmRouter").submit();
    });
  });



<a href="#" id="id_of_your_anchor_tag">Click</a>
```

Try this way,
Hope it helps !